# Windows 2008 - Task scheduler information

Tags: windows-server-2008

Can anyone let me know if there is any equivalent functionality to JT.EXE to provide the following:

A.  Windows Scheduled Task information.  Data returned must include 
      Application name, app parameters, credentials account name, task type, 
      days interval, weeks interval, days of the week, start time, and whether the job is
      disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SCHTASKS command ([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb736357%28VS.85%29.aspx), [examples](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/kbase/WindowsTips/WindowsXP/AdminTips/Utilities/XPschtaskscommandlineutilityreplacesAT.exe.html)) has been available since XP, and should do everything you need. Specifically, to see all the info you wanted, you can type

```
schtasks /query /v
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,

Santhosh.